# R package dev: re-export all instead of depends?

Tags: r

While developing R package I would like to avoid *Depends* in favour of *Imports*.
What would be the differences if instead of using *Depends* I will *Imports* a package and re-export all it's exported functions?

Do I need explicitly call it's internal `.onLoad()` etc. to have it initiated more like *Depends*?

Comment: Why are you re-exporting all the imported functions?

Comment: @RichardScriven I would like to have it as much *Depends* as possible

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want the behavior caused by a specific mechanism, but you want to reinvent the mechanism instead of simply using it?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I believe re-export imported pkg instead of *depends* could be considered a little better practice

Answer (score 3):

I fear you have the wrong premise. `Depends:` are already dead and *everything* you could do there, you can also do with `Imports:` and matching `NAMESPACE` entries.  In fact, you even *should* do that.

Now, the second part of your question is whether you need to re-export everything.  This appears unmotivated.  If you use function `foo()` from package `bar()`, then you simply add `Imports: bar` with a matching `importFrom("bar", "foo")` (or without the quotes--personal styles largely).  And you do not need to re-export `foo()` as `bar` already exports it.

Comment: But I want their names be on the search path after loading my package. The question is how to (semi) emulate *depends* using *imports*.

Comment: @jangorecki if you really want to re-export all the functions you could use both Depends and importFrom, right?

Comment: @GSee yes but the point is to not use *Depends* but get the closest I can get to depends with *Imports*

Comment: The _spirit_ of the new recommendations for `NAMESPACE`  is be explicit in the packages using imported functions.  If I understand what you're after here, then you are actively trying to counteract that spirit. I'd recommends against:  rather spend your energy on the _importing packages_ and make them more explicit importers.

Comment: It looks like best practice to emulate *Depends* is to load package manually each time together with your own package.

Comment: @jangorecki: if you're doing to do that, just use Depends. Doing what Depends does manually, so you can say "I'm not using Depends", is silly.